# Master Equation Second-Order Approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, density-operator, dissipation, open-quantum-systems

I have a problem deriving the master equation using projection operator technique.

If we are given the master equation which reads:

$$
\dot{\rho}= -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_S+H_B+H_I,\rho]+\mathcal{D}\rho
$$
where $\mathcal{D}$ is the Lindblad type dissipator in Markov approximation and Hamiltonians with indexes $S,B,I$ are for system, bath and interaction, respectively.
If we want to trace out the bath Hamiltonian $H_B$ and calculate the system density matrix evolution $\rho_S$ we can do it by considering the projection operator $\mathcal{P}\rho = \text{Tr}_B\{\rho\}\otimes\rho_B=\rho_S\otimes\rho_B$.

First, I redefine the Hamiltonian ocmmutation relations into Liouvillian superoperators:
$$-\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_B,\rho]=\mathcal{L}_B \rho$$
$$-\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_S,\rho]=\mathcal{L}_S \rho$$
$$-\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_I,\rho]=\mathcal{L}_I \rho$$

Now, using the Zwanzig technique of deriving the master equation I have gotten so far:

$$
\dot{\rho}_S=(\mathcal{L}_S+\mathcal{D})\rho_S(t)-\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\text{Tr}_B[H_I, \int\limits_0^{\infty} \text{d} s \,e^{(\mathcal{L}_B+\mathcal{L}_S+\mathcal{D})s}[H_I, \rho_S(t-s)\otimes\rho_B]]
$$

In order to be able to transform to the interaction picture, I need to show is how to transform from the previous equation to this:

$$
\dot{\rho}_S=(\mathcal{L}_S+\mathcal{D})\rho_S(t)-\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\text{Tr}_B[H_I, \int\limits_0^{\infty} \text{d} s \,[e^{(\mathcal{L}^{\dagger}_B+\mathcal{L}^{\dagger}_S+\mathcal{D}^{\dagger})s}(H_I), \rho_S(t-s)\otimes\rho_B]]
$$
where adjoint Liouvillian $\mathcal{L}^{\dagger}$ acts only on the interaction Hamiltonian $H_I$. It is stated [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.0260) (Eq. (7) and (8)) because the second order expansion is done in the coupling $g$ which enters the interaction Hamiltonian in general form: $H_I=g(A\otimes B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are system and bath operators, respectively. But I do not understand how it can be shown.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the wording of your question in the last paragraph. What exactly is the thing that can be shown, but that you don't understand?

Comment: I do not understand how to get from the last but one Eq. to the last Eq. Note the difference - in the former the exponent with Liouville superoperators acts on the commutator of H_I and \rho. However, in the last Eq. the exponent has been brought inside the commutators and acts only on H_I. Moreover, Liouville superoperators are now adjoint.